# Python error while returning a variable from a function

Tags: python

I'm coding an app with Python as backend and when I try to return a variable of a function I get the following error

```
  File "C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Vs projects\backend+frontend\volt-react-dashboard\api\demo_web_app.py", line 43, in translate_write
    return {'text' : response}
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

This is the code I'm using

```
@app.route("/translate", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def translate_write():
    prompt = request.json["prompt"]
    category = request.json["categoria"]

    if category == "one":
        response = translate_1(prompt)

    elif category == "two":
        response = translate_2(prompt)
 
    return {'text' : response}
```

Anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: If neither of your `if` conditions is satisfied then `response` hasn't been assigned any value when you try and use it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to fix the very bug you originally asked about. Doing that makes the question/answers nonsensical and not useful to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is raised when you try to use a variable before it has been assigned in the local context.

```
@app.route("/translate", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def translate_write():
    prompt = request.json["prompt"]
    category = request.json["categoria"]
    response = None # needs to declare

    if category == "one":
        response = translate_1(prompt)

    elif category == "two":
        response = translate_2(prompt)
 
    return {'text' : response}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, response is not defined, because neither if and elif statement are used. So "response" is not reference.

```
@app.route("/translate", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def translate_write():
    response = "No text is available"
    prompt = request.json["prompt"]
    category = request.json["categoria"]

    if category == "one":
        response = translate_1(prompt)

    elif category == "two":
        response = translate_2(prompt)
 
    return {'text' : response}
```

This code should work

Answer (score 2):

As @khelwood pointed out that if none of tests are triggered, then "response" is non existent thus needs to be initialized with a start value.

```
@app.route("/translate", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def translate_write():
    prompt = request.json["prompt"]
    category = request.json["categoria"]
    response = "No translation"

    if category == "one":
        response = translate_1(prompt)

    elif category == "two":
        response = translate_2(prompt)
 
    return {'text' : response}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `category` is equal to `two` or `one`. Then assigning response to a value. But what if `category` was never equal to `two` or `one`. Here is an example showing that.

```
x = 2
if x == 3:
    word = 'three'
elif x == 4:
    word = 'four'
print(word)
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/aspera/Documents/Python/Py_Programs/tests/test.py", line 6, in
>
> print(word) NameError: name 'word' is not defined

Instead you need an else statement after the elif.

```
x = 2
if x == 3:
    word = 'two'
elif x == 3:
    word = 'three'
else:
    word = 'not there'
print(word)
```

**output**

```
not there
```

Answer (score 1):

you could either

- add an `else` clause which would be applied if none of the if and elif evaluate to True
- or you can define response above the if/elif and initiate it with a meaningful default value.

if the if/elif/else does not get more complex than this it would be fine to add an else IMHO.